# JSF : Disable drop down does not set value to backing bean

Tags: jsf-2

I have a requirment in which I need to disable a drop down on certain event through JavaScript and then submit the form. The problem is that when the drop down component is disabled the value in the drop down is not set through the backing bean.

I tried to disable the drop down componenet  through div and span but it has not worked.

Can anyone suggest how can I submit the value of a disabled compoement to the backing bean?
OR do i really need to idsable that component, I mean how can I achive this using div or span?

Answer (score 1):

[Chapter 17.12.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1) of the [HTML forms specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) says the following (emphasis mine)

> ### [17.12.1 Disabled controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1)
>
> ...
>
> When set, the [disabled](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled) attribute has the following effects on an element:
>
> - Disabled controls do not receive [focus](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#focus).
> - Disabled controls are skipped in [tabbing navigation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#tabbing-navigation).
> - **Disabled controls cannot be [successful](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls).**
>
> ...

Note the last point. In other words, they are never submitted to the server. Thus, the behaviour you're seeing is fully correct and expected as per the HTML forms specification.

To achieve your requirement, you need to disable it *after* submission.

Comment: thnaks a lot for your reponse. I can't disable the component after submission. Let me explain a bit in more detail.                                                              1. I have two drop down and the slection of a aprticular value in the first the second one gets disabled. 2. Once the user fills the other fielda it clicks the Complete button and in case of any error the same page is rendred with eroor messages. 3.The problem is on re rendering the page the value of the second drop down does not come as earlier. two solutions in my mind. 1. Put a layer on the componenet ( div or span).

Comment: and get that layer disabled on the event
2. Set the value selected it the second drop down to the backing bean property. But I am not sure that whether it is possible to set the value in backing bean through javascript.

Comment: You can definitely disable the element after submission. Just set the attribute to `disabled="#{bean.submitted}"` or something and set `submitted` to `true` inside the action method.